# Get last quarter of current time in android?

Tags: android-calendar, android-time-square

I am tying to get last quarter of current time in android.

for example the time is `12:45:00` and I need to have:

`12:30:00`

`12:45:00`

or the time is `10:50:00` and I need to have :

`10:35:00`

`10:50:00`

etc.

I write this code and I get result true :

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(cal.getTime());
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -15);
    String oneQuarterBack = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

But If I had `12:45:38` how I can calculate seconds ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Date date = new Date();
int lastQuarterInMillis = 900000;
date.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastQuarterInMillis);
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
String lastQuarter = df.format(date);
```